# eas build error: assets_images_bgbanner.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, eas

I'm trying to build an expo app using command "eas build -p android" and got the error like this:

```
[stderr] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
[stderr] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
[stderr]    > Android resource compilation failed
[stderr]      ERROR:/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/assets_images_bgbanner.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
[stderr]          
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 6m 56s
```

here is my app.json file:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "eworkbook-mobile",
    "slug": "eworkbook-mobile",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.hatieudao.eworkbook"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.hatieudao.eworkbook",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "38e1dc19-4d84-4060-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 31,
            "targetSdkVersion": 31,
            "buildToolsVersion": "31.0.0"
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I dont know what to do with the error since I can't find the file "assets_images_bgbanner.png" or "bgbanner.png" anywhere in my project folder. In the asset folder there is just 4 images: adaptive-icon.png,favicon.png,icon.png,splash.png (just default expo images). Maybe the "assets_images_bgbanner.png" is the default image when build on cloud? If so how can I get rid off it or is there any way to fix this error?

I've tried to create my own "bgbanner.png" and put it in the asset folder, but the error is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it. It's "bg-banner.png" not "bgbanner.png". Moreover, the file seem corrupted or something. I tried to open it with paint and save it. It's work.

Comment: How did this solve the problem? I'm having the same problem right now, however it's not with bgbanner, it's with another asset inside my project

Comment: you should open the image with another app (like paint, photoshop,...) and save it it again to make sure the file don't have any error.  In my case, I can open the image with photoshop and it look completely normal, but when expo build it got error. It's kinda weird, I just simply open the image with paint and save again and it worked. If it's still got error, I think you should use a completely different image.

Comment: Thank you @T.Phustyri, i didnt understand at all, but when I saved the image again, I chose PNG file, and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Open the image in Photoshop save it and replace** the exported image from photoshop to your drawable directory with same name, this solved the issue for my case

Answer (score 0):

Check the file ending for the image and make sure you use the correct extension when importing the file into your code to use. Common formats would be .jpeg and .png

Check to make sure you got it right.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove any "-" characters from my images, then replace all imports of the image in my code to match the new file names. I don't know why but just check what the name of the file is that it's trying to compile, and update your images to match. I think the build removes invalid characters from your asset file names, but then tries to locate them using the original names.